# How to change sender "forge_artifacts@domain.com" in tuleap (project management software)

Tags: postfix

I have been testing tuleap (https://tuleap.net/doc/) and need change sender from "forge_artifacts@domain.com" to xxx@domain.com. Has anyone updated it yet? If you updated please help me.